# Do favorite Dropbox photos automatically download to my Android?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, dropbox

When I tried Dropbox on the iPad, whenever I Favorite a photo Dropbox will automatically download it and it will show up in the Photos app's gallery.

Is this the same behavior for Androids? I have a Galaxy S2 and I have Favorited a bunch of photos, but they do not show up in the Gallery. I can only view them by going to the Dropbox app. Is this correct?

Thank you.

UPDATE: I did a little experiment. I Favorited a picture out of the Sample album and sure enough it downloaded and showed up in Gallery. Then I powered off the phone, and turned it back on, and it is gone from the Gallery even if the file is still in /data/com.dropbox.blabla/files/andsoforth. Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the same. At least in my setup (HTC Desire S). The image I favorite end up in a gallery folder with the same name as the Dropbox folder they are in.

Edit: The gallery app might play a big role in this. On some systems they are known to take quite a while to update etc.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's weird because I could have sworn the pics i favorited were already in the gallery since last week, but today they're gone. When I do a search through my file system the pics only show up under Dropbox/Scratch or something like that.. Why did they disappear from the gallery..

Comment: updated my situation in the original post. thanks!